# My changes to com.canonical.unity-greeter file won't take effect

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

I've installed lightdm and messed around with my login screen settings, but now that I want to use the standard 16.04 login screen(minus the dot-grid) the changes won't take effect.

unity-greeter file location 
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml

Any help would be super appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out what I was doing wrong!

After editing the

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml
```

file you have to run a command after which applies the changes you've made.

the command:

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

will apply the changes made and all you have to do is reboot for them to take effect! :D